# Name convention of appcache vs manifest files?

Tags: html, caching, manifest

What is the correct extension for creating an appcache manifest? I've noticed that it's different in various servers/browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="demo.appcache">
...
</html>
```

an then there are some that

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="demo.manifest">
...
</html>
```